# Table generated by panda's to_latex() too wide. Longtable=True not working

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I want to insert a dataframe in a latex report using the pandas `dataframe.to_latex()` method.

The resulting table is too wide and does not fit in a single page. I noticed that pandas has a `longtable=True` option. Switching it to True and adding longtable in the latex preamble still results in a table too wide for a page.

Here's a working example :

Dataframe

```
data_dic = {'Sample1': {'Users': '4431761.3',
  'Opened app': '25.5%',
  'used once': '5.7%',
  'Android': '8.3%',
  'iOs': '4.6%',
  'Premium access',
  'Purchased': '0.34%',
  'Weeks': '12'},
 'Sample2': {'Users': '168,111.1',
  'Opened app': '5.4%',
  'used once': '2.2%',
  'Android': '69.4%',
  'iOs': '30.6%',
  'Premium access': '10.1%',
  'Purchased': '10.73%',
  'Weeks': '4'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dic, orient='index')
df.to_latex('sample_table.tex', longtable=True, bold_rows=True)
```

Minimal working example in `LaTex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}
\begin{document}
\section*{Table too wide}
Table below
\bigskip
\input{sample_table.tex} 
\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Ideally I'd simply like the table to show broken up and stacked. Wrapping text could also work since it could almost fit in. The solution doesn't have to use the `longtable` option but I am curious to know what the option is for if not for this exact situation.

Thanks !

Comment: There seems to be an error in your table.  In sample1,  line  with   'Premium access' is probably  missing a value and a comma...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I corrected the typo but my question still stands.